# Liferay redirect to createAccountURL with parameters to default input values

Tags: jsp, request, liferay

I want to redirect to /html/portlet/login/create_account.jsp from a StrutsAction.

I see some sample code and I have this code:

```
String createAccountURL = PortalUtil.getCreateAccountURL(request,themeDisplay); 
createAccountURL = HttpUtil.setParameter(createAccountURL,"firstName",firstName);
response.sendRedirect(createAccountURL);
```

... where request=HttpServletRequest, response=HttpServletResponse (inside BaseStrutsAcion request are HttpServlet...)

create_account.jsp page is displayed, but firsName field is empty. I want to have some fields filled by default with that request parameters.

Debugging create_account.jsp I saw that request has not this parameters, but if I do...

```
HttpServletRequest originalRequest = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(request);
firstName = ParamUtil.getString(originalRequest,"firstName");
```

value is here!

The problem is that if parameters aren not in request, input fields are not filled.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* put the parameters in the url you redirect to:

```
response.sendRedirect(createAccountURL + "?firstName=" + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(firstName));
return;
```

However, you *probably should* be forwarding rather than redirecting:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher(createAccountURL).forward(request, response);
return;
```